# T4 Template debugging fine but errors out in normal run mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, t4

I have created a T4 template from scratch to generate DTO classes. Up until yesterday, it was behaving as expected until I added a call to a DbContext class as follows:

```
using (var context = new TenantDbContext())
{
    var entityObjects = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);

    // Processing...
}
```

Now, when the template build is triggered by saving it or when it is triggered by project build, it stops with the following error:

```
Running transformation:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.    at
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating4060E50565D24E6D60BA3E80DDCE2A21E9485A5F4982CD591645549489576DC7687B06DE6C675CAA51175F177B32340E9E07C1C8B0487B2BD65D022D75892D00.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

Oddly enough, when I debug the template, it works fine! I haven't been able to figure out why and haven't found others with similar issues. Any advice would be appreciated.

The imports for this file are as follows:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity.Design" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)ProjectName.Enties\bin\Debug\ProjectName.Enties.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)HouseOfSynergy.PowerTools.Library\bin\Debug\HouseOfSynergy.PowerTools.Library.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)ProjectName\bin\Debug\ProjectName.DataLayer.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.ObjectModel" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="ImagineCapture.Enties" #>
<#@ import namespace="ImagineCapture.DataLayer" #>
<#@ import namespace="ImagineCapture.DataLayer.Contexts" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
```

I do know that all referenced assemblies do exist on their stated paths and that all are built up to date. And it does work while debugging.

Environment:

- VS 2013 Ultimate
- ASP .NET Web App
- Entity Framework 6.3.1
- .NET 4.5
- Windows 8.1 (64-bit)

Comment: Are you building in "Release" mode when you do a project build ? In the T4 script, you referencing a couple of dll in "Debug" path. That might be the cuase of your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to check properties if the those referenced assemblies' Copy to Output Directory property is NOT set to   "Do Not Copy"  ?  I had a similar problem, and as far as I remember, that was the issue!

Comment: @cscmh99: I am building in Debug mode.

Comment: @curiousBoy: The copying properties are fine too. In any case, I have verified that the files exist at the time of building the T4.

Comment: @RaheelKhan yah I had the similar issue and the files were exist as well. What I have done is, cleaned solution, and then even if the properties are set to "Copy always", make them "Do not copy" and then change back to "Copy Always" and try to rebuild again. I know sounds no sense, but that had solved mine! Hope it helps

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your problem? I have a similar issue.

Comment: @JarekMazur: No. I just debug the template after changing entities and have to restart VS since the referenced project outputs get locked up by the *.vshost process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T4 Template is referencing a project within the same solution (albeit one that appears earlier in the build cycle).

Having used the 'Debug' workaround for a while, two reasons come to mind:

- When running the template normally, the T4 host tries to acquire a lock on the referenced assemblies before they are released by the VS build cycle.
- When running the template in `Debug`, the T4 host get enough time to acquire the desired lock but fails to either: (1) Trigger an internal garbage collection so as to release referenced assemblies, or: (2) Fails to terminate as a process itself (although I don't see it as a separate process in the task manager).